# How can i skip files that does not exist file in the repository using python?

Tags: python, xml

I want to download xml file from issue tracking system one by one.It produces error message when file not exist in the repository. I include the python script to better understand my problem.

My code:

```
import urllib.request
for i in range(0,1000):
    issue_id1='DERBY-'+str(i)
    url ="https://issues.apache.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/"+issue_id1+'/'+issue_id1+'.xml'
    s=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    contents = s.read()
    file = open(issue_id1+'.xml', 'wb')
    file.write(contents)

file.close()
```

Stack Track:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PhP/Learning/xmldownlaod.py", line 10, in <module>
    s=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: I do not the all xml files name. That's why, I generate all probable files name then try to download and save. If file not found then generate error. But, I need to download all files that exist and skip if not exist. Please help me if someone can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses ["try except"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) blocks for error handling

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import URLError # the docs say this is the base error you need to catch
for i in range(0,1000):
    issue_id1='DERBY-'+str(i)
    url ="https://issues.apache.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/"+issue_id1+'/'+issue_id1+'.xml'
    try:
        s=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        contents = s.read()
    except URLError:
        print('an error occurred while fetching: "{}"'.format(url))
        continue # skip this url and proceed to the next
    file = open(issue_id1+'.xml', 'wb')
    file.write(contents)
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer. Thanks a lot. But, still have a problem. I found DERBY-16.xml not exist. when the loop reach at 16 then again error generate and found same stack trace.

Comment: DERBY-16.xml does not exist on the server, but the above script just skips it and continues with the reset. You might want to put in a `print('downloaded: "{}"'.format(url))` after the `file.write` so that you can see which ones are succeeding

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I do not why continue (to skip exception) does not work here.

Comment: I think you are expert in python programming. I badly need the above code run properly. I will be very grateful and thankful to you. please help me.

Comment: @RejaulKarim the code I posted works for me. You'll need to edit the question to add the new code you're running along with the output (including exception)

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens on the first iteration of the loop, the url value becomes:

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/DERBY-0/DERBY-0.xml
```

which is a "dead link" and requesting it results into 404 Not Found error.

Start your loop with `1`:

```
for i in range(1, 1000):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is some files is missing with in the range. When file not found then generate error message and quit the program. How can I handle exception. Could you please help me?

Comment: @RejaulKarim ah, that's exactly what Peter's answer is about. Check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for you support. It is really help me lot